# how to rewrite a URL with htaccess modrewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Sorry if this is really simple! I'm not experienced with htaccess rewrites, so I'm just feeling my way around.

I have this URL

```
  /category.php?cat=projects/retail/
```

But I want rewrite it as a clean URL, so it looks like this:

```
  /category/projects/retail/
```

I've written this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category.php/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /category?s=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I found a good article on media temple [Using .htaccess rewrite rules](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/85/Using+.htaccess+rewrite+rules#gs). This explains a bit about the structure of rewrite rule - but I'm still a bit stuck

I know `^` starts the URL to match and `$` ends it. After the `$` the second string defines the new URL.

So this bit after the `RewriteRule`

```
^category.php/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$
```

Defines the original URL, I think the content within the `([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)` means match uppercase, lowercase and hyphens.

I also know `[L]` tells the server to stop

What I don't know is how to rewrite the URL - yet!

Can anyone help?

Comment: stuck how? Did you try it? Did you get an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+category\.php\?cat=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /category/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^category/(.+?)/?$ category.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I only needed to use the 'internal forward from pretty URL to actual one' Thank you so much!